# I use regular expressions in Jenkins, it doesn't work

Tags: jenkins

I use regular expressions in Jenkins, it doesn't work.
Authorization for each job using regular expressions is not allowed.
I know that specific regex don't work in jenkins, but I don't know what it is...

Jenkins Env.

use plugin : manage and assign roles

use regexp : (.*)sandbox(.*)

unrecognized job name : sandbox-credit-gw

jenkins all job count = maybe 500..

jenkins view count = 45

Jenkins authorization using regular expression does not work..

Comment: [Huh](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I know that specific regex don't work in jenkins, but I don't know what it is...

Comment: Start with explaining what Authorization plugin you are using, some examples of the missing data, etc.

Comment: update in main text!

Comment: "it doesn't work." - what does that mean? What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: This means that the regular expression is not recognized. Authorization for each job using regular expressions is not allowed.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: ok. main text updated